# Bootstrap xs columns wrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

For the smallest xs size, even if I have the columns adding up to 12, they don't work as expected if screen width decreases beyond a certain limit. For instance:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-2">
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-8>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1>
           </div>
     </div>
```

I would expect the if I decrease the size the last column will get stacked up to the end of the screen. However, this is not the case. As the screen decreases beyond a certain limit, the last column wraps up toward the beginning of the screen. I have thought about writing css code to give the container min-width. However, I thought that bootstrap might have a better way to handle this

Comment: Well-formatted code is crucial to successful software development. Consider using an editor that does it for you, along with highlighting and error checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13221

At screen widths <360px, the `.col-xs-1` columns start to wrap because..

> "while the column is set to width: 8.333333%;, the
>   column is going to be at least 30px wide because of the 15px padding
>   on either side. Therefore, there's a mismatch and the browser just
>   stacks the columns" - @mdo

The problem can be avoided by not using `col-xs-1` on very small screens. You should also consider if the screen will realistically be resized less than 360px. In most cases it is not.

---

Note: In **Bootstrap 4**, `col-xs-1` is now `col-1`.

---

Related: [Bootstrap grid breaks in smallest size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714749/bootstrap-grid-breaks-in-smallest-size/49717520#49717520)

Answer (score 1):

It works well for me. But your code lacks a closing div and few quotation marks.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-8">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```