# Columns wrap when using React-Boostrap in Gatsby static site

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, gatsby, react-bootstrap

Columns in a row wrap even though xs={..} add up to 12. This happens in all screen sizes. I have checked the following questions and bug reports but they havent helped:

SO Question: [Bootstrap xs columns wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806334/bootstrap-xs-columns-wrap)

Gatsby Github Issue: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/17914

The workaround in the issue did not help me.

Versions:

- "gatsby": "^2.18.5",
- "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16"
- "bootstrap": "^4.4.1"
- "react": "^16.12.0",

Code Snippet:

```
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          {
            tech["name"].map(db => {
              let icon = svgs[toLower(db)];
              return(
                <Col xs={colSize}>
                  <Container>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs={4} style={{"maxHeight": "100px", "maxWidth": "100px"}}>
                        <img src={icon} alt={db}/>
                      </Col>
                      <Col xs={8}>
                        <h5>{db}</h5>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Container>
                </Col>
              )
            })
          }
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Generated HTML:
[image: Generated HTML]

The 4th column (SQL Server) wraps around
[image: The 4th column wraps]

The elements are rendered correctly after a reload
[image: Elements are rendered correctly after reload]

Website Link: https://tokern.io/cheat_sheet/

Comment: Your link does not work.

Comment: Gah! Fixed. Used a hyphen instead of underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding padding to the box and using the default box-sizing mode. To see why this is problematic, review [the box-sizing documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) or [this article on box-sizing on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

To resolve the issue, add `box-sizing: border-box` to the `.col` declaration.

Comment: Thank you. This was indeed the problem. Also thanks for pointing out the article on box-sizing.